# Как правильно вытащить свойство из переменной

Tags: php, xdebug

Понадобилось вытащить свойство **index_mod** из переменной $**filter**. Через xDebug я вижу где находится это свойство (выделенно, на скрине снизу), но не понимаю как правильно обратится и вытащить его.

Опция Copy path дает результат:

```
$filter->*Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute*filterSetting->_data["index_mod"]
```

Но этот результат не возможно использовать в коде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так может не надо namespace класса поля в код тащить? зы: подозреваю, что поле приватное/протектед

Comment: Ну вы гляньте что там в этом классе, с высоким шансом есть метод типа ``getData()`` и подобное

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Там действительно есть нужные геттеры. Если это возможно, я бы хотел дергнуть это свойство из этой переменной/через нее, а не создавать новый экземпляр этого класса